# kernel_task CPU usage with SIP on a MacBookPro8,2 with no battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, cpu, kernel, sip

Is there any **evidence or technical documentation** to support the notion that System Integrity Protection can cause excessive use of the CPU by `kernel_task` in some situation?

### Background

No battery. All Apple operating systems on an external hard disk drive, limited (by the MacBookPro8,2) to USB 2.0.

With Sierra, and with pre-release High Sierra, when not booted in safe mode I nearly always found that `kernel_task` hogged the CPU.

My usual workaround was safe mode.

After considering answers to the following questions:

- [kernel_task consumes 500% CPU on AC power, sometimes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72498/8546) (2012-11-24)
- [How to disable the SpeedStep when using MacBook Pro without a battery?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116193/8546) (2014-01-06)
- [Kernel_task boosts CPU to 300%-500% (Yosemitte MBP 2011 without a battery)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/170450/8546) (2015-02-04)
- [kernel_task hundreds of % CPU yet cpu frequency is being lowered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179150/8546) (2015-04-01)
- [Very high kernel_task CPU usage after updating to Yosemite 10.10.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/194422/8546) (2015-07-04)
- [Macbook Pro with abnormal CPU usage and unrecognised battery. How to alternative SMC reset](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/203025/8546) (2015-09-02)

– I aimed to move (set aside) the following file:

`/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources/MacBookPro8_2.plist`

Prerequisite to the move:

- disable System Integrity Protection (SIP).

---

After using `csrutil(1)` in Recovery OS 17A264c to disable SIP, I booted High Sierra in normal mode …

… I was pleasantly susprised to find that with the `.plist` still in place:

- in normal mode **without** SIP, the CPU was no longer hogged.

Shut down, started, no hogging.

Started 10.12, no hogging, updated to 10.12.5, restarted, no hogging.

2017-06-10 around 16:50 the Mac unexpectedly stopped. When started, to 10.12.5, I noticed that **SIP was re-enabled** (not by me). No hogging.

Started Recovery OS 17A264c, **disabled SIP**, restarted to 10.12.5, no hogging …

Comment: Discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38019636#38019636

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/how-can-i-disable-cpu-throttling-and-cpu-disabling